# Unable to upload image or excel file to s3 in serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I have created a sample serverless framework, it has a function to upload files on s3 but I am facing issues while uploading files(Files are getting uploaded but it turns out to be corrupt). 
Please refer below code of node js where I have created the route, controller and service for file upload on s3 with the serverless framework

```
//Router
app.post('/api/fileUpload', controller.fileUpload);

//Controller
exports.fileUpload = (req, res) => {
    let params = {
        Bucket: 'BucketName',
        Key: 'keyofAWSS3',
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        Body: data,
        ACL: 'private'
    };

//to create file on S3
return s3Service.CreateToS3(params).then((fromResolve) => {
    console.log(fromResolve);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});

}

//Service
exports.CreateToS3 = (params) => {
let s3 = new AWS.S3();

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //Upload as a file to S3
        s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {

        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }

        resolve(data);

     });
    });
};
```

Below are the serverless.yml settings
    service: service-name-of-lamda-function

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  timeout: 90
  stage: production
  memorySize: 128
deploymentBucket:
    name: bucketname
functions:
  funciton-name-of-lambda:
  handler: index.handler
  events:
    - http: ANY /
    - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code and/or the resulting file that is created?

Comment: @alex Please refer my code above

Comment: Is the `s3.putObject` process completing before the Lambda sends the response and shuts down?